# How to call a method on a period of time in swing?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a frame with a `JTextField` and a `JButton`. 
When I press I want to call a method that updates the JTextField`s text at every 4/5/8 seconds.
Could anyone help me with the code ?? (thank you)

```
The code:    

import javax.swing.*;
public class Gui{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public Gui(){

frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
JButton    bu = new JButton("Button");

  bu.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

               for(int i=0;;i++){
               tf.setText("" + i);
               }
        }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: See [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: What do you mean, "at every 4/5/8 seconds" ? Is it "wait 4s, update, wait 5s, update, wait 8s, update" ?

Comment: @barjak in my case, set the text after 4 sec, then set it again (update) after 8/9/100 sec

Comment: Please do have  a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837751/1057230)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, as @trashgod has pointed out, I'd be using the [java.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), the main reason is that it supports calling notifications within the `EDT`, as well as some (generally minor) management methods to help make life easier

Comment: The name is `trashgod` and not `trashjob` :( +1 though for the rest :-) And it's `EDT` not `ETD` Event Dispatch Thread :( Please do rectify that thingy too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use timers : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

You might want to start the timer when the `actionPerformed` method is called.

Though BEST bet with Swing, is the use of [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), as it allows you to update your GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: `java.util.Timer` isn't _wrong_, but `javax.swing.Timer` is probably a more convenient choice.

Comment: If the solution with timers worked, you might wan to click on the up arrow next to my answer, for giving me some reputation points ! :-)

Comment: Please refer to the latest API (JDK7) instead of the 1.4 JDK

Comment: I agree with Robin. JDK 1.4 is a little out of date.

Comment: @BaL : Pardon me for the edit, but as humbly suggested by @trashgod, `javax.swing.Timer` is actually the real way to update your GUI on the `EDT`. For the rest, You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)