# How to move Jlabel from one JPanel to another

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, mouse-listeners

I have many `JPanel`s and one `JLabel`. When I click on one `JPanel` I want my `JLabel` (contains a picture) move to this `JPanel`. How can this be done by code? I'm coding in NetBeans.

Comment: I started to make something like chess game. The chess squares are 64 JPanels. I have JLabel(image) that represent a pieces. Firstly I want to know how to move this jlabel around the JPanels by clicking on JPanel...(sorry bad english)

Comment: Don't move the labels, just change their icons.

Comment: I understand your opinion, but I want to have only 32 labels(pieces)

Comment: see this it can be helpful for u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008724/mouseclicked-event-to-setbackground-of-a-panel

Comment: I hope this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837751/1057230) be able to help you in that, though it used `JButton` instead of `JPanel` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The premise is simple, but the actual solution may depend on what it is you want to achieve.

Because a component can only exist within a single container at a time, you only need worry about adding it to the new container...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LabelMover {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LabelMover();
    }

    public LabelMover() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BasePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class BasePane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public BasePane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
            MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                CellPane pane = new CellPane();
                pane.addMouseListener(handler);
                add(pane);
            }
            label = new JLabel(":)");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            ((CellPane)getComponent(0)).add(label);
        }

        public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Component source = e.getComponent();
                if (!label.getParent().equals(source)) {
                    ((CellPane)source).add(label);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }

        }

        public class CellPane extends JPanel {

            public CellPane() {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(50, 50);
            }

        }        
    }    
}
```