# ActionListener in GUI. Functionality doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, actionevent

I've got a question on my program, the program contains one single class `Calculator`, which should implement a calculator who is able to operate with `+` and `*` with the type `double`.

I have written a GUI for that calculator, too, which already works fine, but the buttons don't work, although I've implemented the function

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

The mistake has to be somewhere in this function I guess. I just don't know why the functionality of the buttons doesn't work. Here's the code.

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Calculator () {}

    JTextField parameter1;
    JTextField parameter2;
    JTextField ergebnis;
    JFrame window;
    Container cont;
    /* this function works fine */
    public void calculator_GUI() {     
       builds the GUI of the calculator,     
       this.window = new JFrame("Calculator");
       window.setSize(300,300);
       this.parameter1 = new JTextField("Parameter1...", 10);
       parameter1.addActionListener(this);
       this.parameter2 = new JTextField("Parameter1...", 10);
       parameter2.addActionListener(this);
       this.ergebnis = new JTextField("Ergebnis...", 5);
       ergebnis.addActionListener(this);
       JButton multiplizieren = new JButton("*");
       parameter1.addActionListener(this);
       JButton addieren = new JButton("+");
       parameter1.addActionListener(this);
       JButton clear = new JButton("clear");
       parameter1.addActionListener(this);
       this.cont = window.getContentPane();

       FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
       cont.setLayout(flowLayout);

       cont.add(parameter1);
       cont.add(parameter2);
       cont.add(ergebnis);
       cont.add(multiplizieren);
       cont.add(addieren);
       cont.add(clear);
       window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       window.pack();
       window.setVisible(true);;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
       String label = e.getActionCommand();
       if (label.equals("*")) {
           String a = parameter1.getText();
           String b = parameter2.getText();
           double zahl1=Double.parseDouble(a);
           double zahl2=Double.parseDouble(b);
           double result = zahl1*zahl2;
           String c = String.valueOf(result);
           ergebnis.setText(c);
       }
       else if (label.equals("+")) {
           String a = parameter1.getText();
           String b = parameter2.getText();
           double zahl1=Double.parseDouble(a);
           double zahl2=Double.parseDouble(b);
           double result = zahl1+zahl2;
           String c = String.valueOf(result);
           ergebnis.setText(c);
      }

      else if (label.equals("clear")) {
           String z = "";
           ergebnis.setText(z);
      }
      else { 
           window.dispose(); 
      }
}


  public static void main (String[] args) {   
      Calculator MyCalculator = new Calculator();
      MyCalculator.calculator_GUI();
  }
}
```

Comment: "*which already works fine, but the buttons don't work*" - Then it doesn't work fine :D

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Are breakpoints in the handler hit? What happens?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a copy-paste error:

This:

```
    JButton multiplizieren = new JButton("*");
    parameter1.addActionListener(this);
    JButton addieren = new JButton("+");
    parameter1.addActionListener(this);
    JButton clear = new JButton("clear");
    parameter1.addActionListener(this);
```

Should be:

```
    JButton multiplizieren = new JButton("*");
    multiplizieren.addActionListener(this);
    JButton addieren = new JButton("+");
    addieren.addActionListener(this);
    JButton clear = new JButton("clear");
    clear.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks for the help kuporific .  I've still got one question to the comment of nachokk: 
how do I control that Action Event? Then I have to put the e.getActionCommand() in each overwritten actionPerformed method, right?

Comment: @rikojir you don't need any more actionCommand, i will update answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is what @kuporific says but instead of doing `implements ActionListener` in your top level container you can:

1. create private classes, or
2. use anonymous classes

Example using `Swing Action` (anonymous classes)

```
JButton multiplizieren = new JButton("*");
multiplizieren.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                String a = parameter1.getText();
                String b = parameter2.getText();
                double zahl1=Double.parseDouble(a); // this can cause NumberFormatException
                double zahl2=Double.parseDouble(b); // this can cause NumberFormatException
                double result = zahl1*zahl2;
                String c = String.valueOf(result);
                ergebnis.setText(c);
         }
});
JButton addieren = new JButton("+");
addieren.addActionListener((new ActionListener(){
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            String a = parameter1.getText();
            String b = parameter2.getText();
            double zahl1=Double.parseDouble(a);
            double zahl2=Double.parseDouble(b);
            double result = zahl1+zahl2;
            String c = String.valueOf(result);
            ergebnis.setText(c);
         }
});
```

So instead of using `ìf-else` everywhere you can isolate associated actions for each button.

Besides you can add in the textfield a documentFilter that only accept numbers, or use a `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: `if-else` construct is far better than the overhead related to creation of a new class for each `JComponent`'s related `Action`. Though your first point is more suitable, regarding creation of private Class, as cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837751/1057230)

Comment: @nIcEcOw yeah, you can use all if-else rather than programming in object oriented way for performance..

Answer (score 1):

Add actionListener to button instead of textfield